# Data Driven Pages- Can i grey out non-zoomed to layers of each page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, data-driven-pages

I am making a map book of plots in a municipality. I am using data driven pages, but I want each page to only show the current plat and grey out the other plats on the edges. Is there a code I can use to do this? Using 10.1

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You have tagged `python` in your question - are you after code, or do you just want to know how to do it in ArcMap?

Comment: I'd love to run a python script to make this happen on all pages, but a manual way in arcmap will work too.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a page definition query. Create a copy of the data driven pages index layer. Set up a Page definition query to show only the pages that don't match. Make that area grey and put it at or near the top of your table of contents. Could make it partially transparent. See the screenshot, in my example Vancouver Facets grey is 10% transparent. You may have issues with labels.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great, I didn't know that page definition queries existed.

Comment: Can you mark the question as solved if this solution worked for you?